# Avoid OpenStreetMap loading shops, monuments, restaurants and any other POIs?

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap, point-of-interest

I am loading OpenStreetMap using Leaflet.

More or less I'm doing this:

```
var objmap = new L.Map(p_objCapaMapa, mapOptions);
var osmUrl = 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
capaMapa= new L.TileLayer(osmUrl);
objmap.addLayer(capaMapa);
```

Very easy and it works. But the map is loading a lot of Points of Interest like restaurants, shops, etc A lot of little icons over the tiles of the map.

How can I avoid the map load all these points?

I need Leaflet to just load the map with its roads, squares, streets, parks, etc.

In JavaScript Google Maps API there is a way of not loading these POIs that comes with the map but I do not know a way to avoid POIs over OpenStreetMap using Leaflet.

We have searched a lot for the web but we still do not have a solution to this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simple answer: You can not.

Unlike Google maps API, these icons are part of the pre-rendered tiles you get from openstreetmap.org, and there is nothing you can do about it.

You may however look for other tile sorces based on Openstreetmap data, like [Stamen](http://maps.stamen.com) .

Or render your own tiles with tools like Maperitive. Then you are free to leave out any data you don't want to see in your own map.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It save me a lot of time.

Comment: @Falinsito, you can show your appreciation by both upvoting and accepting the answer. You can visit the [tour] for more information.

Comment: See also https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_servers - in particular the "no labels" tiles.